# place results in a textbox after click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i'm working on an auto complete with jquery which is working perfectly. the results get displayed as the user types. Now the problem is when the user starts typing and the results appear, when the user clicks on the desired results, it doesn't get placed in the textbox

JS

```
$(function(){
$(".search_tab").keyup(function() 
{ 

var searchid = $(this).val();
var dataString = 'fname='+ searchid;
if(searchid!='')
{
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost/myapp/search.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(html)
    {
    //console.log(html)
    $("#result").html(html).show();
    }
    });
}return false;    
});

$('.search_tab').click(function(){
    jQuery("#result").fadeIn();
});
});
```

HTML

```
  <input type="text" class="search_tab" placeholder="Search" autocomplete="off">
   <div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Do you have an example snippet that gets returned from the AJAX call?

Comment: add an id to your text box `<input type="text" class="search_tab" placeholder="Search" autocomplete="off" id="textSearch"> `
and after  `$("#result").html(html).show();` fill the text box `$("#textSearch").val(html);`

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do some event delegation over the items that get placed into the `div#result` element. You'll want something like this:

```
$('#result').on('click', 'RESULT_ITEM', function (event) {
  $('input.search_tab').val(event.target.innerHTML);
});
```

Where `RESULT_ITEM` is a selector that matches the individual items that are listed in the autocomplete results.

Comment: [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) is deprecated in version 3 of jQuery. Since the replacement, [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) already exists, it's probably best to start using it now.

Comment: Huh. I was not aware. It seems like its overloading the meaning of `on` to mean two different things. No sense in arguing with JQuery though. Fixed.

Comment: @tengbretson Overloading is a big part of the jQuery philosophy, like using `.click()` to trigger a click or add a click listener, depending on whether you give an argument.

Comment: can you put this results in my script? i'm kinda confused i'm somehow new to jquery

Comment: I'll need to see an example of an ajax response from your web service.

Answer (score -2):

While i dig into this have you considered using jQuery UI to acomplish this?

https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

This is a nice and polished way of doing exactly what you are wanting.

Not quite sure why I am getting down voted really as my suggestion is a perfectly valid solution to this problem...

That being said here is a working fiddle for you.

https://jsfiddle.net/wxr5y5gu/

The main part you seem to be missing is something like this:

```
$('#result').on('click','li',function(){
    /* I used li as the element as im unsure what your response html looks like */
    let newValue = $(this).text();
    $('.search_tab').val( newValue );
    $('#result').html('').hide();
});
```

That will clear the results, set the clicked value, and hide the results box for you.

That contains a working soution for you. As i dont have access to AJAX your local resources I had to extrapolate and create my own auto fill to show how it works in principal however i can certainly help you tailor the solution to your needs.

This solution uses your code and is compatible with all current jQuery versions.

Comment: Again... not sure why this is getting downvoted as I have provided TWO working solutions to the problem as well as a fiddle with the code showing that its working... if i got some feedback I could be more helpful.